# Custom WooCommerce rewrite URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting

Currently, the product URL goes like this:

- https://dabaonow.com.sg/product/product-name/?vendor=vendor-name

E.g.

- https://dabaonow.com.sg/product/72-hours-slow-cooked-beef-rice/?vendor=tie-fun-wan

Is it possible to change it to

- https://dabaonow.com.sg/vendor-name/product-name

E.g.

- https://dabaonow.com.sg/product/tie-fun-wan/72-hours-slow-cooked-beef-rice/

I somehow managed to get the above URL structure but see 404 error.

---

I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/ plugin for the marketplace.

The website is under development so you will not be able to see the above links. Kindly suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"..I somehow managed to get the above URL structure but see 404 error.."._ 
Can you elucidate this in your question?

Comment: Ok, Please check the codes here https://codeshare.io/ax4jBL (link expires in 24 hours)

Comment: I removed my answer because I don't think it will be helpful. I think if you want to organize the URL structure as vendor/product/ you need to create the vendor post type and then have the products be posts within that post type. Or you could create vendors as categories so that they always get prefixed.

But for the sake of admin sanity it will make more sense to organize the vendors as individual post types. If you have too many vendors though then you're best solution is to look at a Wordpress multi site solution where each vendor is their own site and store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to achieve this pushing taxonomy name into the product URL. Steps as follows:
1) Set the Custom Base under Product permalinks as "/%product_brand%/"

2) Edit a product and create/ set the product brand (you want to show in the url). I used WCMP vendor name to keep in sync and understandable.

3) Add the following code to the functions.php

```
function dab_prefix_filter_vendor_permalink( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {
    if('product' == get_post_type($post->ID)){
        $brands = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "product_brand", array("fields" => "all"));
        if(!empty($brands) && false !== strpos($post_link, '%product_brand%')){
            $post_link = str_replace('%product_brand%', $brands[0]->slug, $post_link);
        }else{
            $post_link = str_replace('%product_brand%/', '', $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'dab_prefix_filter_vendor_permalink', 10, 4 );
```

Note: I have added an exception to display product instead of %product_brand% in the url in case brand is not assigned.

Happy coding!

Comment: You can also use below:

`if('product' == get_post_type($post->ID)){
 $vendor_id = get_post_field('post_author', $post->ID);
 $_vendor_page_slug = get_user_meta($vendor_id, '_vendor_page_slug', true);
 $post_link = str_replace('%product_brand%', $_vendor_page_slug, $post_link);
}
return $post_link;`